# Async function stops running on await_limit()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to run this async function code, but for some reason it will stop running after `await _limit()`, not sure what am I doing wrong.

Basically I'm trying to go to a specific image dir, do something for each image and then update some meta-tags into some other dir that contains json files. The code will basically stop working after `await_limit()`

````
const path = require("path");
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");

const { RateLimit } = require('async-sema');
const { fetchWithRetry } = require(`${basePath}/utils/fetchWithRetry.js`);

const { LIMIT } = require(`${basePath}/src/config.js`);
const _limit = RateLimit(LIMIT);

const allMetadata = [];
const regex = new RegExp("^([0-9]+).png");

async function main() {

  console.log("Starting upload of images...");
  const files = fs.readdirSync(`${basePath}/build/images`);
  files.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.split(".")[0] - b.split(".")[0];
  });
   for (const file of files) {
    try {
      if (regex.test(file)) {
        const fileName = path.parse(file).name;
        let jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`);
        let metaData = JSON.parse(jsonFile);

        if(!metaData.file_url.includes('https://')) {

          console.log(`code executes until here`);
          await _limit()
          const url = "https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files";
          const formData = new FormData();
          const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(`${basePath}/build/images/${file}`);
          formData.append("file", fileStream);
          const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {Authorization: 'my API key here'},
            body: formData,
          };
          const response = await fetchWithRetry(url, options);
          metaData.file_url = response.ipfs_url;
          metaData.image = response.ipfs_url;

          fs.writeFileSync(
            `${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`,
            JSON.stringify(metaData, null, 2)
          );
          console.log(`${response.file_name} uploaded & ${fileName}.json updated!`);
        } else {
          console.log(`${fileName} already uploaded.`);
        }

        allMetadata.push(metaData);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Catch: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${basePath}/build/json/_metadata.json`,
    JSON.stringify(allMetadata, null, 2)
  );
}

main();```


///config.js file starts here

const basePath = process.cwd();
const { MODE } = require(`${basePath}/constants/blend_mode.js`);
const { NETWORK } = require(`${basePath}/constants/network.js`);

const network = NETWORK.eth;

// General metadata for Ethereum
const namePrefix = "name of collection here";
const description = "description of collection here";
const baseUri = "ipfs://NewUriToReplace";

const solanaMetadata = {
  symbol: "YC",
  seller_fee_basis_points: 1000, // Define how much % you want from secondary market sales 1000 = 10%
  external_url: "https://www.youtube.com/c/hashlipsnft",
  creators: [
    {
      address: "address here",
      share: 100,
    },
  ],
};

// If you have selected Solana then the collection starts from 0 automatically
const layerConfigurations = [
  {
    growEditionSizeTo: 10, // With Cap
    layersOrder: [
      { name: "Background" },
      { name: "Short" },
      { name: "Body" },
      { name: "Neckchain" },
      { name: "Tshirt" },
      { name: "Hoodie" },
      { name: "Facial Expression" },
      { name: "Beard" },
      { name: "Piercing" },
      { name: "Glasses" },
      { name: "Cap" },
    ],
  },
];

const shuffleLayerConfigurations = false;

const debugLogs = false;

const format = {
  width: 2000,
  height: 3000,
  smoothing: false,
};

const gif = {
  export: false,
  repeat: 0,
  quality: 100,
  delay: 500,
};

const text = {
  only: false,
  color: "#ffffff",
  size: 20,
  xGap: 40,
  yGap: 40,
  align: "left",
  baseline: "top",
  weight: "regular",
  family: "Courier",
  spacer: " => ",
};

const pixelFormat = {
  ratio: 20 / 128,
};

const background = {
  generate: true,
  brightness: "80%",
  static: false,
  default: "#000000",
};

const extraMetadata = {
  external_url: "external url here"
};

const rarityDelimiter = "#";

const uniqueDnaTorrance = 10000;

const preview = {
  thumbPerRow: 5,
  thumbWidth: 50,
  imageRatio: format.height / format.width,
  imageName: "preview.png",
};

const preview_gif = {
  numberOfImages: 5,
  order: "ASC", // ASC, DESC, MIXED
  repeat: 0,
  quality: 100,
  delay: 500,
  imageName: "preview.gif",
};

module.exports = {
  format,
  baseUri,
  description,
  background,
  uniqueDnaTorrance,
  layerConfigurations,
  rarityDelimiter,
  preview,
  shuffleLayerConfigurations,
  debugLogs,
  extraMetadata,
  pixelFormat,
  text,
  namePrefix,
  network,
  solanaMetadata,
  gif,
  preview_gif,
};

const AUTH = "API here";
const LIMIT = 2;
````

Comment: Does the catch run?

Comment: What did debugging show the value of `LIMIT` from the configuration file to be? [RateLimit source](https://github.com/vercel/async-sema/blob/main/src/index.ts)  suggests it needs to be a non-zero positive integer.

Comment: @traktor when I ```console.log(LIMIT);``` on the file above (uploadFiles.js) I get on console the value ```undefined```. And if I ```console.log(_limit())```, I get ```Promise { <pending> }```

Comment: @traktor I have added to the code above the config.js file too.

Comment: @danh catch does not run.

Basically nothing run after `await _limit()`, i've tried a few console logs after that and nothing gets logged, so assuming the code stops there. No errors are thrown into the console either. Anything consoled logged before `await_limit()` gets logged Ok

Comment: Well if `LIMIT` is `undefined` that is obviously the issue, as @traktor said. [This](https://github.com/vercel/async-sema/blob/603842b82e68e24b76eb0e74dae66de1eda468b4/src/index.ts#L223) `delay` will become `NaN`, and the semaphore is never released.

Comment: Try exporting  `LIMIT`  in `config.js` by moving its definition to  _before_  setting `module.exports`, and include `LIMIT` in the property list of the object assigned to `module.exports`.  An explicit answer to the question is that there is a typographical error of omission in `config.js`.

Comment: Solved @traktor ! Now is working.

As you suggested I did two things:

1 ->  I defined `LIMIT` before `module.exports`
2 ->  I included `LIMIT` in the module.exports array

Now it works perfectly.